# How to read some partitions of delta table?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake

I have a partitioned delta table stored in ADLS (partitoned on date column).

How to read only that data which is of the past one year, i.e data is something `2020-**-**`?

Comment: Could a mere `WHERE` help here? In other words, the query optimizer should push down the filter condition to the delta lake to handle. Have you tried it out?

Comment: predicate pushdown should definitely work

Answer (score 0):

Load in partitioned raw table based on date

```
raw_df = spark.read.format('delta').load(raw_data_path + 'tablename/partitionname=specifieddate')
```

This is the code I use usually to retrieve a certain partition from ADLS

Comment: No, it's incorrect method for Delta

Answer (score 0):

You just need to read table and filter out the data you need - Spark will perform predicate pushdown & will read only data from the matching partitions.  It's simple as (assuming that column is called `date`):

```py
df = spark.read.format("delta").load("your-table-root-path") \
  .filter("date >= '2020-01-01' and date <= '2020-12-31'")
```